# Sniff traffic going to network device

Tags: networking, udp, packet-sniffers

I have a device who connect the home thermostat to internet with wifi.
This device send information about home temperature to producer and using their app I can see this information on the smartphone.
I want to have this information directly without by interrogation on device.
I find with nmap it use 4097 udp port. Now I want to sniff the packet it send or receive to understand what type of command can I use.

What is the best way to do it?
I'm thinking to use my ubuntu has wifi router, conncet the device to it and sniff traffic. It is possibile??

Thanks

---UPDATE----

I do it with arpspoffing, and now I'm able to capture udp packes send from the thermostat with wireshark. But this packet data are not human readable... How can I understand this data? 
This is the data I sniff:

0000   70 71 bc 6e 64 2e fc e8 92 2d cf 3c 08 00 45 00
0010   00 47 01 f5 00 00 ff 11 93 2f c0 a8 01 02 b0 38
0020   b4 9e 10 01 07 dc 00 33 c7 71 02 01 c2 01 fe e8
0030   92 2d cf 3c ac b4 05 00 00 00 14 00 8a 01 fc e8
0040   92 00 11 6d 58 41 06 00 2d 01 00 03 b7 06 00 01
0050   08 07 11 00 8a

```
pqnd.-<EG83o-<mXA-
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a new monitoring interface with

```
iw phy phy0 interface add wlan0mon type monitor
```

Activate the interface

```
ifconfig wlan0mon up
```

Monitor the interface with a packet capture utility

```
tshark -i wlan0mon
```

Filter the capture to your thermostat device only

```
tshark -i wlan0mon -Y eth.addr==<FOUND SOURCE>
```

Full packet details is obtained by adding `-V` flag.

---

Other tools proposal

- `airmon-ng start wlan0` to start the monitor mode
- `netsniff-ng`, `tcpdump`, `wireshark`, `ngrep` for capture